# items not appending to list, or list returning as empty in python?

Tags: python, list, append

In my code, the item percentgrade is not appending to the list lnpercentgrade in each iteration of a for loop, but I'm not sure why. When I try to sum the items in lnpercentgrade (at the end of the code), I am returned 0 because lnpercentgrade is empy.
I have lnpercentgrades declared as a global variable outside of the maininput() function, because otherwise at the bottom of the code when I try to sum(lnpercentgrades), I am returned "lnpercentgrades not defined".

I'm guessing lnpercentgrades is not being modified somehow inside the maininput() function, even though I am sure I typed it correctly before the .append function.

What I am really trying to do is match the sum(lnpercentgrades) with 100, but when I enter 5 items all with value of 20, the sum is 0 instead of 100.

The important lines are marked with arrows <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

```
lnpercentgrades = []   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
def maininput():
    numtests = int(input("Enter # of tests:"))
    numassign = int(input("Enter # of assignments:"))
    numquizzes = int(input("Enter # of quizzes:"))
    numlabs = int(input("Enter # of labs:"))

    l = [numtests, numassign, numquizzes, numlabs]
    ln = ["test", "assignments", "quizzes", "labs"]
    lnpercentgrades = [] <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    testwavg = None
    numassignwavg = None
    numquizzeswavg = None
    numlabswavg = None
    numfinalwavg = None

    lnwavg = [testwavg, numassignwavg, numquizzeswavg, numlabswavg]
    print(l[0])
    print("Is there a separately weighted final?")
    yn = int(input("Enter 1 for yes. 2 for no:"))
    while (yn > 2 or yn < 1):
        yn = int(input("Enter 1 for yes. 2 for no, please:"))

    n = 4 
    if yn == 1:
        final = 1
        l.append(final)
        ln.append("final")
        lnwavg.append(numfinalwavg)
        n = 5


    for i in range (n):
        if l[i] > 0:
            print("Enter % of total grade of",ln[i],":") 
            percentgrade = float(input("")) 
            print("you inputed:", percentgrade)
            lnpercentgrades.append(percentgrade) <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            percentgrade = percentgrade*.01 


            varscoreslist = []
            for x in range(l[i]):
                print("Enter score of", ln[i], x+1,"as a fraction:")
                from fractions import Fraction
                inputfrac = input("")
                varscore = float(sum(Fraction(s) for s in inputfrac.split())) 
                #the above converts fractional inputs to decimals
                varscoreslist.append(varscore)

            if ln[i] == "labs":
                score = sum(varscoreslist)
            else:
                sumscores = sum(varscoreslist)
                score = sumscores/l[i]

            lnwavg[i] = score*percentgrade

maininput()
print(lnpercentgrades)
print("sum of percent of grades", sum(lnpercentgrades)) <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

if float(sum(lnpercentgrades)) != 100:  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    print("Sorry, the grade percent of each item enter did not sum to 100:")
    print("Program will rerun.")
    input("")
    maininput()

coursegrade = sum(lnwavg)
print("Your course grade is:", coursegrade)

input("")
```

Comment: why not to return it as a function result - then you don't need to specify it before function

Comment: RocketDonkey already done all explanations you need

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At first glance, it looks like you may have a scoping issue. You are modifying the list inside of the function, but keep in mind that is a local copy of the list. Despite the fact you are declaring it in the outer scope, you are not prefacing it with `global`, which means it instead creates a function-local copy, does its business and then exits, not affecting the 'main' list at all.

I would suggest modifying your function to return the lists you want so that you can use them as you'd expect. Here is a basic example:

```
def MyFunc():
    l1 = ['my', 'first', 'list']
    l2 = ['another', 'list']
    return l1, l2

main_list, second_list = MyFunc()

print(main_list)
print(second_list)
```

Which will output:

```
['my', 'first', 'list']
['another', 'list']
```

If you really want to keep the variable in the outer scope, you would have to preface it with `global` inside of your function (I would probably go with the first method though):

```
main_list = []
second_list = []

def MyFunc():
    global main_list
    global second_list
    main_list = ['more', 'good', 'stuff']
    second_list = ['another', 'list']


MyFunc()

print(main_list) # ['more', 'good', 'stuff']
print(second_list) # ['another', 'list']
```

Comment: Hmmm... What does In and Out do?

Comment: @ShaltNot Sorry, that was probably more confusing than it needed to be - that is using the IPython interpreter. I will replace with something you would put in a module.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate the help though. You can still leave this current code up if you wish, and add on the other version. I am going to try the global variable though.

Comment: @mgilson Ha, naturally I pick a horrible example - I'll update with something that will actually fail.

Comment: @RocketDonkey -- Thats better.  +1

Comment: @mgilson I was just about to +1 that answer of yours - design aspect aside, pretty clever :)

Comment: yep, simply adding a new line: "global lnpercentgrades" did the trick. Will flush out a few more bugs and most likely accept your answer soon. 
@mgilson why do you say global isn't needed in this case?

Comment: @ShaltNot -- Sorry, `global` wasn't needed in the first example provided in rocket's original example.  His update rendered that comment mostly obsolete.  I'll delete.  As a side note, `lnpercentgrades[:] = []` would also work.

Comment: @mgilson Ah, ok, thanks for clarifying. What does the [:] part do?

Comment: @ShaltNot -- It's a slice assignment.  Basically, it deletes everything in a list in place.